# Regex : Everything in group except white space

Tags: regex

I have this regex right here :

```
^(@include rem\(\s*(.*)),\s*(.*)\)
```

That matches this string :

```
@include rem( padding-top, $alert-padding );
```

I want to be able that the group with $alert-padding ignores the white space at the end. I tried doing :

```
^(@include rem\(\s*(.*)),\s*(/S)\)
```

replace the .* by /S but it doesn't match.

You can play around with the regex here :
https://regex101.com/r/9rouVU/1/

Comment: Try backslash, not forward slash `\S`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `\S+` to match 1 or more non-whitespace characters:

```
^(@include rem\(\s*(\S+))\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*\)
```

See the [regex dem0](https://regex101.com/r/mPUnRV/1)

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(@include rem\(\s*(\S+))` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `@include rem\(` - a literal substring `@include rem(`
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(\S+)` - Group 2 capturing 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\s*,\s*` - 0+ whitespaces, `,` and again 0+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)` - 1+ non-whitespace symbols
- `\s*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `\)` - a literal `)`.

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what is the difference between /S and /S+ ?

Comment: Yes, `\S` matches a single non-whitespace character. `+` is a quantifier that matches 1 or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern. So, `\S+` matches 1 or more non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the match in the second group lazy and then match for further optional whitespace:

```
^(@include rem\(\s*(.*)),\s*(.*?)\s*\)
```